# Reference to pointer and malloc

Tags: c++, c++11, malloc, decltype

Consider

```
int *p;
auto & pp = p;

 pp = (decltype(pp))malloc(sizeof(decltype(*pp))); //line1
 pp = (decltype(p))malloc(sizeof(decltype(*p))); //line2
```

why `line1` is not acceptible but `line2` is fine suggesting they are of different types.

Why `pp` and `p` are not of same type?

Comment: Do you know what `decltype(p)` and `decltype(pp)` are? If yes, the answer should be obvious. If no, *that* should be your question.

Comment: Why using `malloc` BTW ?

Comment: I'm betting that the errors you failed to include in your post tell you exactly why.

Comment: @KerrekSB, the question was why `pp` and `p` are not of same type

Comment: Because one's a reference and the other isn't would be my first guess.

Comment: @user4581301: Then *that* should be your question.

Answer (score 1):

pp is a reference to an int *

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293667.aspx

"The following code fragment initializes variable x to type int, variable y to a reference to type const int, and variable fp to a pointer to a function that returns type int."
C++

```
int f(int x) { return x; }
int main()
{
    auto x = f(0);
    const auto & y = f(1);
    int (*p)(int x);
    p = f;
    auto fp = p;
    //...
}
```